# Where stored array, if I declared it after return?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, c++11

I have code C++11:

```
template<std::size_t n>
static inline constexpr uint32_t mask() noexcept 
{ 
    static_assert(n <= 32, "!");
    using list = uint32_t[]; 

    return list{
        0x0u, 
        0x1u,       0x3u,       0x7,        0xfu,       0x1fu,       0x3fu,       0x7fu,       0xffu, 
        0x1ffu,     0x3ffu,     0x7ffu,     0xfffu,     0x1fffu,     0x3fffu,     0x7fffu,     0xffffu, 
        0x1ffffu,   0x3ffffu,   0x7ffffu,   0xfffffu,   0x1fffffu,   0x3fffffu,   0x7fffffu,   0xffffffu, 
        0x1ffffffu, 0x3ffffffu, 0x7ffffffu, 0xfffffffu, 0x1fffffffu, 0x3fffffffu, 0x7fffffffu, 0xffffffffu
    } [ n ]; 
}
```

Q: where is stored `list` array?  (in static memory, auto memory, or nowhere stored)?

Comment: This is a question you should ask your compiler, not us. But still, why would it be stored?

Comment: It'll probably be optimized out completely and the values would be inlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a normal function, it would be a temporary, stored in automatic memory. Since `n` is a compile time constant, it may be optimised to simply return the value, removing the array.

However, this is `constexpr`, so the return value should be computed at compile time. The array should not exist at run time at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since `n` in the function can not be a variable, e.g.

```
size_t n;
std::cin >> n;

std::cout << mask<n>() << std::endl;
```

will fail to compile, because `n` is not a constant at compile-time, the compiler wouldn't need to store the array at all. In general, a `constexpr` function should not generate any "code" other than some sort of constant value.

My compiler appears to not accept the code posted here - probably because it's a bit ancient by now (it's a gcc 4.6.3 - I also tried clang++, but it fails because it tries to use the 4.6.3 headers, which apparently isn't in "clang flavour").

Of course, it's much easier to write this:

```
template<std::size_t n>
inline constexpr uint32_t mask() noexcept 
{ 
    static_assert(n <= 32, "!");

    return (1u << n) -1;
}
```

To cope with the special case where n == 32 (and avoiding UB, although in most archtiectures, the above would probably do the right thing):

```
template<>
inline constexpr uint32_t mask<32>() noexcept 
{ 
    return ~0;
}
```

Comment: your mask  result undefined behavior if n == 32 .

Comment: @MikeSeymour & @Kurshid: Thanks, I have added a `u` to ensure. Even if you had to add an extra `if (n == 32) return 0xffffffff;`, I'd say this is a better solution than a long list of values.

Comment: @Mike: This is NOT well-defined.  Overflow (pushing non-zero high order bits off the left) would be, but shifting by a value greater than or equal to the width is still undefined, even for unsigned types.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You're right. After twenty years, I should have learned that I'll *never* understand how basic arithmetic works in C++.

Comment: Good fix.  Note that real-world architectures that account for *many* of your deployment targets will treat `1u << 32` the same as `1u << 0`, because they implicitly mask the shift operand and only use the low 5 bits.  And this is why it is specified as undefined behavior even for unsigned types.

Comment: your specialization isn't compiled:
g++ -std=c++11 -O2  -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" 
example.cpp:13:1: error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class
 static inline constexpr uint32_t mask<32u>() noexcept
 ^
Compilation failed.

Comment: @KhurshidNormuradov: The static can certainly be removed, so I will do that. It should have no effect, since `constexpr` shouldn't give any code anyway.